# When creating a SpecFlow Scenario Outline how do I skip a field in the examples table for a row where the field is not valid

Tags: specflow

I currently have a SpecFlow Scenario where one of the fields are not valid for a specific row. In the below examples table, the 3rd row is not valid for UOM. How do I skip UOM for specifically this row only?

```
      Examples: 
  | Name                         | Taxing Authority     | Tax Code             | Rate Type | Currency | UOM | Tax Type | Status   |
  | OK Tax Rate Fixed            | Propane Education an | 1A                   | Fixed     | EUR      | bbl | SSales   | Active   |
  | Ok Tax Rate Flat             | Internal Revenue Ser | 12345ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO | Flat      | USD      | gal | CiSales  | Active   |
  | OK Tax Rate Percent INACTIVE | State of Oklahoma    | 1A$                  | Percent   | (Empty)  |     | MFuel    | Inactive |
```

Comment: What do you mean 'skip the field'? The UOM will be passed to the step as an empty string. Why can't you just handle the string being empty in your step?

Comment: It is not enabled in the UI meaning that the user could not interact with the field.

Comment: It's still not clear what you mean. Maybe you should give an example of the step you are calling. I still don't understand why you can't just not use that field in the code if it's passed in empty

Answer (score 0):

Scenario Outline: All fields are valid

Given...

When...

Then...

```
 Examples: 
  | Name                         | Taxing Authority     | Tax Code             | Rate Type | Currency | UOM | Tax Type | Status   |
  | OK Tax Rate Fixed            | Propane Education an | 1A                   | Fixed     | EUR      | bbl | SSales   | Active   |
  | Ok Tax Rate Flat             | Internal Revenue Ser | 12345ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO | Flat      | USD      | gal | CiSales  | Active   |
```

Scenario Outline: Tax percent inactive

Given...

When...

Then...

```
 Examples: 
  | Name                         | Taxing Authority     | Tax Code             | Rate Type | Currency | UOM | Tax Type | Status   |
  | OK Tax Rate Percent INACTIVE | State of Oklahoma    | 1A$                  | Percent   | (Empty)  |     | MFuel    | Inactive |
```

Comment: It's probably just easier to add a separate scenario. that way you can add a different step method for the special case